# Unresolved reference error when importing basic modules on Pycharm 4.0.1 and OS X Yosemite 10.10.1

Tags: virtualenv, pycharm, osx-yosemite

After upgrading PyCharm to version 4.0.1 and OS X Yosemite to version 10.10.1, I encountered the following problem:

When trying to import basic modules, e.g: `import time` or `import sys`, PyCharm marks the import as an "Unresolved reference" (red underline) and does not recognise the module name.

When trying to figure it out, I noticed that while writing the module name the auto completion pop up is finding a match on the '**lib-dynload**' folder within my virtualenv path (/Users/myname/Envs/envname/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload) rather than on the '**site-packages**' folder. 
There are also added to the PYTHOPATH in this order (lib-dynload before site-packages).

As a workaround I removed the lib-dynload path from the "project interpreter" setting window in PyCharm which made PyCharm recognise the basic modules again, but I am not sure what other impacts this change might have.

My Question is whether there is a way to reproduce the original behaviour PyCharm had so it would recognise the basic modules without tampering the paths of the virtualenv used as a project interpreter.

I am using a separate installation of Python (/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.6/bin/python) and virtualenv version 1.10.1.

Comment: Have you added in the Project Interpreter panel your virtualenv ? You checked that everything is fine ?Usually i create the virtualenv from command line, then I give the path to pycharm using "Add Local" in the Project Interpreter panel in the Settings.

Comment: Yes. When going to PyChram -> Preferences -> Project -> Project Interpreter, the project interpreter name is set to be my-virtual-env-name. When clicking the setting (gear icon) next to it, then "More...", choosing my virtualenv interpreter and clicking the "show paths for the selected interpreter" icon (little tree structure icon) I can see the list of paths in use, whereas lib-dynload is listed before site-packages. This is also the window I used to remove the lib-dynload path (using the minus icon), which so far works as my in question workaround.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably a bug, a [recent youtrack issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-14567) seems to match your problem.

Comment: I still watch this issue. Unfortunately it does not show progress for a long while, but it describes exactly my problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I'm using pycharm 4.0.1 and virtualenv 1.11.6 and everything works fine to me, but i'm on Arch Linux not OSX.

You may try to recreate the virtualenv, and invalidate and restart the pycharm cache, then wait for pycharm to index again your virtualenv.

Don't know if this is too much of a hassle to you, maybe it is worth a try.

This is a django project tree i tried:

[image: project tree]

Comment: It was too problematic for me to recreate the virtualenv, so I kept my workaround eventually. Thank you for the response!

Comment: Recreating the virtualenvironment through pycharm fixed it for me.  Had to reinstall everything via pip again of course, but not a big deal considering everything is working now.  Although I'm on Mac, thanks for pointing me in the right direction!